# Simple SQL Query Returns Null For All Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query a simple table to get a users id based on their username. For some reason I am getting a null result for all of my queries.

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
user_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
username text not null,
password text not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Inserting a tuple:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, 'joe', '1234');
```

Selecting user id based on username:

```
SELECT 'user_id' FROM `users` WHERE 'username' = 'joe'
```

Returns 0 rows... yet when I click on the table users I can see the row with username joe.

I am executing the queries in PHPMyAdmin with the users table selected so I am pretty sure it is not a schema issue.

Comment: An inverted comma denotes a string

Comment: Learn to use single quotes properly; they are not used for column names.  I'm voting to close as a simply typographical error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491/87015

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'joe'
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting an empty result is because you're using the wrong column delimiter in your select query. Try swapping the apostrophe for a backtick character.

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'joe';
```